# A Word for the Gesture: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Tags: single-word-requests, gestures

What may be a word for this gesture: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯?

It's kind of a shrug, like when someone asks where you want to go for dinner, but any option will do, so instead of saying anything you just raise your arms like this: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

It's a gesture of indifference, the closest word to it is `shrug'.

Comment: It would help us if you include an example sentence showing how you want to use the phrase, and explain why "shrug" doesn't work for you. Also, are you open to phrases rather than single words?

Comment: It seems our markup does bad things to the backlash in here ... `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` comes out as ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I replaced the single backslash in my answer with a double backslash and that sorted it.

Comment: I don't know about you, but for me looking at this emoticon makes me think of the informal expression **dunno**: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dunno

Comment: Please see this guidance from Stack Exchange management regarding [***Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity***](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2160/2085).

Answer (score 4):

I would say there is no verb other than "to shrug" to describe what you say. However, the word **meh** can be used as an interjection or adjective to convey this meaning:

*"Where do you want to go for dinner?" "Meh."*

Comment: Btw, it's "go **for** dinner".

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "go to dinner." In fact, I find it more natural-sounding.

Answer (score 3):

It is officially called *shrug* or *person shrugging*. [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/shrug/), the ultimate reference work in these questions, has this entry:

> A person shrugging their shoulders to indicate a lack of knowledge about a particular topic, or a lack of care about the result of a situation.
>
> Displays as raised shoulders, sometimes in conjunction with raised arms and flat hands. The shrug gesture in text (emoticon) form is known as the shruggie and typed as: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
>
> Person Shrugging was approved as part of [Unicode 9.0](https://emojipedia.org/unicode-9.0/) in 2016 under the name “Shrug” and added to [Emoji 3.0](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-3.0/) in 2016.

The Unicode documentation lists it [here](https://www.unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html#1f937) with the code **U+1F937**, and in addition to the CLDR Short Name *person shrugging*, it lists these Other Keywords: *doubt | ignorance | indifference | person shrugging | shrug*. (CLDR stands for [Common Locale Data Repository](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository).)

Answer (score 0):

Clueless would be a good word for this reaction

Comment: Not really. It could also mean that you don't know how to exactly express whatever your emotion is.  You can shrug your shoulders in many situations...

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As a reminder, Stack Exchange is interested in *definitive* answers, those which answer a question completely, including appropriate examples and references. Your answer would be strengthened if you [edit] it to include demonstrative links, for example. The site [tour] and review the [help] may offer further guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't mind or I couldn't care less :)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As a reminder, Stack Exchange is interested in *definitive* answers, those which answer a question completely, including appropriate examples and references. Your answer would be strengthened if you [edit] it to include demonstrative links, for example. The site [tour] and review the [help] may offer further guidance.